# Simple HTML Dom not working as expected

Tags: php, html

Hey so am trying to parse this html but its not working as expected i managed to get the title and link but i need to get the Size but its just not selecting it for some reason i tried this method

Please note i'm new to Simple HTML Dom and i'm just guessing how to select these.

Example it outputs now

Title > Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED 720p HDTV x264-W4F [eztv]

Link > /ep/148425/pokemon-s19e14-dubbed-720p-hdtv-x264-w4f/

Size > Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED 720p HDTV x264-W4F [eztv]

I need it:

Title > Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED 720p HDTV x264-W4F [eztv]

Link > /ep/148425/pokemon-s19e14-dubbed-720p-hdtv-x264-w4f/

Size > 523.10 MB

```
$html = str_get_html("<td align=\"center\" class=\"forum_thread_post\">
    <a href=\"pokemonlink\" rel=\"nofollow\" class=\"download_1\" title=\"Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED HDTV x264-W4F Torrent: Download Mirror #1\"></a>
    </td>
    <td align=\"center\" class=\"forum_thread_post\">175.32 MB</td>
    <td align=\"center\" class=\"forum_thread_post\">4h 23m</td>
    <td align=\"center\" class=\"forum_thread_post_end\"><a href=\"/forum/discuss/148426/\" rel=\"nofollow\" title=\"Discuss about Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED HDTV x264-W4F [eztv]:\"><img src=\"/ezimg/s/1/3/chat_empty.png\" border=\"0\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" alt=\"Discuss\" title=\"Discuss about this show\"/></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr name=\"hover\" class=\"forum_header_border\">
    <td width=\"35\" class=\"forum_thread_post\"><a href=\"/shows/1253/pokemon/\" title=\"Pokémon Torrent\"><img src=\"/ezimg/s/1/3/show_info.png\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Show\" title=\"Show Description about Pokémon\"></a><a href=\"http://www.tvmaze.com/episodes/762956/pokemon-the-series-xy-19x14-an-explosive-operation\" target=\"_blank\" title=\"More info about Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED 720p HDTV x264-W4F [eztv] at tvmaze.com\" onclick=\"trackOutboundLink('http://www.tvmaze.com/episodes/762956/pokemon-the-series-xy-19x14-an-explosive-operation'); return false;\"><img src=\"/images/tvmaze-16x16.png\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" border=\"0\" alt=\"TVmaze\"/></a></td>
    <td class=\"forum_thread_post\">
    <a href=\"/ep/148425/pokemon-s19e14-dubbed-720p-hdtv-x264-w4f/\" title=\"Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED 720p HDTV x264-W4F [eztv] (523.10 MB)\" alt=\"Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED 720p HDTV x264-W4F [eztv] (523.10 MB)\" class=\"epinfo\">Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED 720p HDTV x264-W4F [eztv]</a>
    </td>
    <td align=\"center\" class=\"forum_thread_post\">
    <a href=\"pokemonlink\" rel=\"nofollow\" class=\"download_1\" title=\"Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED 720p HDTV x264-W4F Torrent: Download Mirror #1\"></a>
    </td>
    <td align=\"center\" class=\"forum_thread_post\">523.10 MB</td>
    <td align=\"center\" class=\"forum_thread_post\">4h 23m</td>
    <td align=\"center\" class=\"forum_thread_post_end\"><a href=\"/forum/discuss/148425/\" rel=\"nofollow\" title=\"Discuss about Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED 720p HDTV x264-W4F [eztv]:\"><img src=\"/ezimg/s/1/3/chat_empty.png\" border=\"0\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" alt=\"Discuss\" title=\"Discuss about this show\"/></a></td>
    </tr>");

$tdTorrents = $html->find("td[class=forum_thread_post]");
foreach ($tdTorrents as $torrent) {
    if(($torrent->find("a[class=epinfo]", 0))) {
        $title = $torrent->find("a[class=epinfo]", 0)->innertext;
        $link = $torrent->find("a[class=epinfo]", 0)->href;
        if (strpos($torrent->innertext, "MB") !== false || strpos($torrent->innertext, "KB") !== false || strpos($torrent->innertext, "GB")!== false) {
            $Size = $torrent->innertext;
            print "<br>Title > ".$title."</br>
                <br>Link > ".$link."</br>
                <br>Size > ".$Size."</br>";
        }
    }

}
```

Any help is greatful thanks the html am using is down there.

```
<td align="center" class="forum_thread_post">
<a href="pokemonlink" rel="nofollow" class="download_1" title="Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED HDTV x264-W4F Torrent: Download Mirror #1"></a>
</td>
<td align="center" class="forum_thread_post">175.32 MB</td>
<td align="center" class="forum_thread_post">4h 23m</td>
<td align="center" class="forum_thread_post_end"><a href="/forum/discuss/148426/" rel="nofollow" title="Discuss about Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED HDTV x264-W4F [eztv]:"><img src="/ezimg/s/1/3/chat_empty.png" border="0" width="16" height="16" alt="Discuss" title="Discuss about this show"/></a></td>
</tr>
<tr name="hover" class="forum_header_border">
<td width="35" class="forum_thread_post"><a href="/shows/1253/pokemon/" title="Pokémon Torrent"><img src="/ezimg/s/1/3/show_info.png" border="0" alt="Show" title="Show Description about Pokémon"></a><a href="http://www.tvmaze.com/episodes/762956/pokemon-the-series-xy-19x14-an-explosive-operation" target="_blank" title="More info about Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED 720p HDTV x264-W4F [eztv] at tvmaze.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.tvmaze.com/episodes/762956/pokemon-the-series-xy-19x14-an-explosive-operation'); return false;"><img src="/images/tvmaze-16x16.png" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="TVmaze"/></a></td>
<td class="forum_thread_post">
<a href="/ep/148425/pokemon-s19e14-dubbed-720p-hdtv-x264-w4f/" title="Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED 720p HDTV x264-W4F [eztv] (523.10 MB)" alt="Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED 720p HDTV x264-W4F [eztv] (523.10 MB)" class="epinfo">Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED 720p HDTV x264-W4F [eztv]</a>
</td>
<td align="center" class="forum_thread_post">
<a href="pokemonlink" rel="nofollow" class="download_1" title="Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED 720p HDTV x264-W4F Torrent: Download Mirror #1"></a>
</td>
<td align="center" class="forum_thread_post">523.10 MB</td>
<td align="center" class="forum_thread_post">4h 23m</td>
<td align="center" class="forum_thread_post_end"><a href="/forum/discuss/148425/" rel="nofollow" title="Discuss about Pokemon S19E14 DUBBED 720p HDTV x264-W4F [eztv]:"><img src="/ezimg/s/1/3/chat_empty.png" border="0" width="16" height="16" alt="Discuss" title="Discuss about this show"/></a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `Size` is a part of `alt` attribute of `a.classinfo`.

Comment: <td align="center" class="forum_thread_post">523.10 MB</td>   << i need to get that without the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

> `$e->next_sibling ()`     Returns the next sibling of element, or null if not found.

Because `td` with size is the next sibling of the next sibling of `td` with `a.epinfo`, you can try:

```
if(($torrent->find("a[class=epinfo]", 0))) {
    $title = $torrent->find("a[class=epinfo]", 0)->innertext;
    $link = $torrent->find("a[class=epinfo]", 0)->href;
    if (strpos($torrent->innertext, "MB") !== false || strpos($torrent->innertext, "KB") !== false || strpos($torrent->innertext, "GB")!== false) {

        $Size = '';
        // next sibling of next sibling           
        $size_el = $torrent->next_sibling()->next_sibling();
        // make sure it's not NULL
        if ($size_el) {
            $Size = $size_el->innertext;
        }

        print "<br>Title > ".$title."</br>
            <br>Link > ".$link."</br>
            <br>Size > ".$Size."</br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Also failed output is blank

Comment: Updated. `td` with size is a next sibling of a next sibling of a current `td`.

Comment: Awesome thank you didn't know i can use nextsibling twice.